# SageMager Studio Notebook Kernel keeps starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Trying to execute cells in an Amazon SageMager Studio Notebook I continuously receive the message "Note: The kernel is still starting. Please execute this cell again after the kernel is started." The bottom status bar claims "Kernel: Starting..." The "Running Terminals and Kernels" overview shows a running instance ml.t3.medium with running app datascience-1.0 and kernel session corresponding to the notebook title. I tried restarting SageMaker Studio and opened it in another region but neither helped.

Comment: Are there any lifecycle configuration setup?

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be some proxy/firewall/network issue. It works from another system/network.